# mysql_pconnect not working

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I have created a php connection file as explorecalirfornia.php content as below.

```
#FileName="Connection_php_mysql.htm"
# Type="MYSQL"
# HTTP="true"
$hostname_explorecalirfornia = "localhost";
$database_explorecalirfornia = "explorecalirfornia";
$username_explorecalirfornia = "root";
$password_explorecalirfornia = "";
$explorecalirfornia = mysql_pconnect($hostname_explorecalirfornia, $username_explorecalirfornia, $password_explorecalirfornia) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
```

I have include this php file in my page using command

```
<?php require_once('Connections/explorecalifornia.php'); ?>
```

when I test the php code using local host following error is throwing.

[image: img]

Please help me to complete my tutorial.

Comment: Warning
This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: it already says deprecated, why not change it to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` like the error suggests

Answer (score 1):

```
  Either @mysql_pconnect($hostname_explorecalirfornia, $username_explorecalirfornia, $password_explorecalirfornia) or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);  //@ infront of mysql_pconnect or use below written code

    $mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DBNAME);
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_ *functions` are deprecated and will no longer be used in the future. Use `mysqli_* functions` or `PDO` instead. Befriend [**The PHP Manual.**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php)

```
$explorecalirfornia = new mysqli($hostname_explorecalirfornia, $username_explorecalirfornia, $password_explorecalirfornia);

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: I tried to continue with the same and now following errors is appearing. 

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7ruul9z0u9txwbn/Fatal%20error.PNG?dl=0

Comment: @Daz that's so easy man. You just need to make sure that the path is right of the file you are including is right or the file exists